# GPRS modem ATD timeout unspecified, how to interrupt?

Tags: gprs

With my GPRS modem I encounter very long durations for ATD*99***1# command used for establishing the connection (more than 2 minutes in some areas with low RSSI - Received signal strength indication).

My question is twofold:

1. As the timeout for the ATD command is not specified in the datasheet of the modem, what is the maximum duration that I could expect ? 5, 10 minutes ? (I would like to have the timeout in the chat script consistent with the timeout of the modem)
2. In case I cannot manage a reasonable timeout, how could I interrupt the ATD command (the modem is still in AT-command mode, not in data mode, so +++ won't work I suppose)

For information the sequence in nominal case is:

```
send(ATD*99***1#)
recv(CONNECT)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got some answers:
The ATD command is decomposed internally as:

- GPRS attachment
- switch to data mode
- PDP context establishment

The timeout of the GPRS modem for GPRS attachment is 5 minutes, and this cannot be interrupted.

The timeout for PDP context establishment is 160 seconds. This one can be interrupted by +++.

This is of course dependant on the modem you use.